Contradicting interpretations when including factor variables into GAM
the model I built is like this:
bam(n ~ s(age, k = 10, m = 2) + 
    s(hh_size, k = 7, m = 2) +
    s(age, by = pp, k = 10, bs = "tp", m = 1)  +
    s(hh_size, by = pp, k = 7, bs = "tp", m = 1) +
    (employment_2cat + weekend + region + marital_2cat + education_2cat)* period * place + 
    s(token, k = 864, bs = "re") + 
 s(Bundesland, k = 16, bs = "re"), data = halle_data, family = nb(), method = "fREML", 
drop.unused.levels = FALSE)
 # pp is the interaction between period and place. 

After fitting the model, summary() was used to get the Parametric Coefficients. emmeans(), pairs(), and contrast() were applied to get the effect of period and place on each of the factor variables. But the results seems not right.

From the result of the summary() of the model, it can be interpreted that being “Not Employed” is associated with a 25.5% increase in the log count of the contact number compared to being Employed. But from the result of the pairs(), it seems being employed is associated with a higher level of contacts. This conflicting interpretation also appears for the weekend variable.

From the result of the summary(), there is a higher number of contacts during the weekend compared to the weekdays. But from the result of pairs(), there are more contacts that happened during the weekdays instead of the weekend.
------- update: age in the summary(model) and visualization -------


This part is about the result of the numeric variable from the model.

In the default R coding of variables, the coefficient and p-value reported by summary() for employment_2cat is the value when all of its interacting predictors (period, place) are at their reference or 0 values. That's also the case for all the other predictors (weekend, region, marital_2cat,education_2cat) involved in interactions with period and place.
It's seldom helpful to examine any individual coefficients from summary() for predictors involved in interactions, unless you happen to be interested specifically in their associations with outcome when all their interacting predictors are at reference or 0 values. Thinking that those individual coefficients mean anything other than that when there are interactions is a common confusion on this site (and was for me, too, when I first started dealing with interactions in multiple regression). You were wise to use emmeans() to evaluate specific hypotheses of interest; those are what you should focus on.

Thank you! So when I get the result of the summary(), for the factor variables, I should use emmeans() to explore further, but for the continuous variable, I can use the result from the summary().

@Chao that's true only if the continuous variable is NOT involved in an interaction. If it is, then the same problem occurs. The coefficient for a continuous variable involved in an interaction will only be for the situation where all of its interacting predictor variables are at reference level (categorical predictors) or at 0 (continuous predictors). Using emmeans() takes all of the individual and interaction coefficients and their variance-covariance matrix into account.

I am trying to use emmeans() on age for this model, the result is weird...

In your model, age is included both by itself and in a smooth with pp as a "by" variable. I'm not sure that's OK (I don't have much experience with mgcv functions). Furthermore, with respect to the "by" variable, the manual for s() says: "For the numeric by variable case the resulting smooth is not usually subject to a centering constraint (so the by variable should not be added as an additional main effect)." But you say "pp is the interaction between period and place," which is included as a main effect in your model.

Thank you, I have the age as a smooth term in the model result. I updated the summary(model) and visualization of the age in the question part. With this visualization, I think I can compare the age effect on contact numbers between period and place.
